# SSL certificate from Netlify - HTTPS with Digital Ocean

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, digital-ocean, netlify

I am new at deploying web applications. I have set up a web server on Digital Ocean that is running on top of NGINX. Besides, I have a front application running on Netlify. The connection between the server and the web is not established (error 400) and I suspect a port problem.

I have double-checked the CORS policy, but my guess is that NGINX listens to port 80 for HTTP request (open), while Netlify automatically creates a SSL certificate which makes my requests go through the HTTPS protocol.

My question is: do I need to do anything else than setting up Nginx on the server side in such a way it listens to port 443 (HTTPS port), or do I need to generate another SSL certificate on the server side?

My intuition is option 1, but I feel lost with all these notions.

Answer (score 0):

its CORS error, your Netlify HTTPS will not allow you to hit insecure HTTP API. You need to enable HTTPS on your droplet on Digital Ocean by providing a Domain Name to your application. Follow the [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04)